# Getting 'ConnectionResetError' error while downloading data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: java, python, windows, beautifulsoup, jsoup

I am getting ConnectionReset error when downloading data using BeautifulSoup but the same thing works using JSoup.

I have experience using Jsoup and wanted to learn scraping using Python. I am trying to download content from a website using BeautifulSoup and I am getting the below error,

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I have checked few sources and kept sleep of 5 to 10 secs after every URL fetch but Im still getting the error for every 50-70 hits.

I tried the same using JSoup and it worked perfectly.

Can someone help me if I am missing something. My code is below,

test.py

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
f.write(str(soup) + "\n")
print (url)
time.sleep(10)
```

test.java

```
Document d = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Method.GET)
             .timeout(20000).ignoreContentType(true).ignoreHttpErrors(true)
             .execute().parse();
```

Comment: Use proxies and random user agents.